# algorithm for create blog page via for or foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I try create a simple system blog page with this algorithm:

```
<?php
$page = floor(10 / 10);

$limit = 40;
$num= 100;
$page = 1;
for ($record = 0; $record <= $num ; ++$record ) 
{

   if($record % $limit == 0) 
   {
       if(!($record < $limit))
       {
           echo 'page:'.$page.'<br/>';
           for($id = $record - $limit +1 ; $id <= $record ; ++$id)
           {
               echo $id.'<br/>'; 
           }
           $page ++;
           echo '<hr>';
       }
   }
}
?>
```

but it seems do not work for example... on $limit=40 I lost last 20 id!

can help me to improve this algorithm or suggest me a better way>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$limit = 40;
$items = 100;
$page_counter = 1;

$excess_items = $items % $limit;
if($excess_items > 0) 
    $total_page = ($items / $limit) + 1;


$current_count = 1;
while($page_counter <= $total_page){
    echo 'total_page:'.$page_counter.'<br/>';

    $cutting_count = 1;
    while($cutting_count <= $limit){
        if($current_count <= $items)
            echo $current_count.'<br/>'; 

        $cutting_count ++;
        $current_count ++;
    }
    echo '<hr>';
    $page_counter++;
}
?>
```